# Using multi GCD to load image in TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I am using Asynchoronous GCD for UITableView to load image when "cellForRowAtIndexPath" with callback.

In my tableView, each row have 2 product (which mean, in each row, i have to load 2 images using asynchoronous GCD) -> as the following:

[image]

Here my code for load image asynchoronous

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Some code to init CustomCell
    //Load Label1
    //Load Label2
    //Load image1
    if(product1.thumImgData != nil){
        //Update image from datasource
    } else{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:product1.thumImg]];
            if (imgData) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                if (image) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        CustomViewProductByCategory *updateCell = (id)[self.tvProduct cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                        if (updateCell){
                            product1.thumImgData = imgData;
                            updateCell.imgProduct1.image = image;
                            [updateCell.indicatorProduct1 stopAnimating];
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    }

    if(product2.thumImgData != nil){
        //Update image from datasource
    } else{
    //load image2
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:product2.thumImg]];
            if (imgData) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                if (image) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        CustomViewProductByCategory *updateCell = (id)[self.tvProduct cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                        if (updateCell){
                            product2.thumImgData = imgData;
                            updateCell.imgProduct2.image = image;
                            [updateCell.indicatorProduct2 stopAnimating];
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
  }
```

I guess, because of i am using 2 GCD in cellForRowAtIndexPath, so sometimes, i could not load some images.

Is anybody know how to solve this?
Tks in advance.

Comment: I had same issue, how large is your image data? Best to create a smaller thumbnail image to use within the tableview cell.

Comment: I have requested to server send small data. it just 80x80px

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't using GCD, the problem is that cells don't work like that. You have a tableview with lots of rows. Having tableview rows is cheap, cells are not cheap. Therefore, iOS will reuse the same cells again and again. It only needs as many cells as you can see on the screen, not as many as you have rows.

So in your asynchronous code, do *not* try to load a cell and set the image. Instead, store the image in the data model, and tell the tableview to redraw the line of the tableview that has changed.

Comment: You mean that, all images would be loaded and saved in a data model using GCD. After load all images in this data model, we redraw tableview?

Comment: I think you are wrong, because i have just comment GCD which load "image2". And tableview work ok!!